# What is the topology of this quotient of $S^2 \times S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, fiber-bundles

So suppose you take an $S^2$, then you put an $S^1$ fiber over it which degenerates by smoothly shrinking to a point at its poles. What is the topology of this space in more familiar terms (assuming some nicer representation is possible)?

To be clear, it is almost $S^2 \times S^1$, except at two points where the $S^1$ degenerates to a point, so it's $S^2 \times S^1$ quotiented by the action of the $S^1$ at two points, $(x,\theta)\sim(x,\theta')$ for $x$ equal to each pole. You might think of this in terms of having to specify two longitudes at every latitude.

Comment: Your description of the fibration is very unclear, it is also uncler if it is a fibration at all.

Comment: It degenerates at two points. As I explain, it is $S^2 \times S^1$ quotiented by the identification of all points $(x,\theta) \sim (x,\theta')$ when $x$ is one of the two poles of the $S^2$ and $\theta,\theta'$ are arbitrary in the $S^1$.

Comment: I see: Then you should not call it a fibration. I doubt there is a nice alternative description since your space is not a manifold.

Comment: The map you describe is not a fibration. The fibers are just points at the two special points of the two sphere and $S^1$ on the regular points. Since the base is path connected, all fibers would be homotopy equivalent if the map is a fibration, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: OK, I've tweaked the terminology to hopefully appease you a bit ;) It's just a slightly degenerate version of a fiber bundle, that's how I want to think of it. Anyway, back to the question then. @studiosus It's still no worse than a pseudomanifold, being a manifold pinched smoothly at two points. There's some hope?

Answer (score 2):

Your space is the suspension of the 2-dimensional torus.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the way of looking at it. (For others' reference, this is essentially viewing $S^2$ as being the suspension of $S^1$ and then adding another circle. This is essentially how my "two longitudes" interpretation works.) Can I ask, related to your comment above: why is it clear this *cannot* be a manifold? After all, the suspension of a $n$-sphere is a $(n+1)$-sphere, which is very definitely a manifold.

Comment: @Sharkos: this cannot be a manifold since links of the two special points are tori rather than homology spheres.